# Are Shiva, Parvati, and their children, the only Gods who dwell on Earth?

Tags: shiva, puranas, gods, ganesha, devi

I was referring to Mount Kailasha. Among the Trimurti, Vishnu, along with Lakshmi, and Brahma, along with Sarasvati, appear to dwell in other realms. So do the other Gods.

Comment: There's Lord Hanuman, several other *tattva devtas*, all said to be residing on Earth itself.

Answer (score 2):

No. Gandharvas, Yakshas, Rakshasas, and gods live in Mahendra mountains.

[Mahabharata source that describes how Karna went to Mahendra Mountains where other gods reside](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a002.htm)

> With this knowledge about his birth and family, Rama received him kindly and said, 'Thou art welcome!' at which Karna became highly glad. While residing on the Mahendra mountains that resembled heaven itself, Karna met and mixed with many Gandharvas, Yakshas, and gods. Residing there he acquired all the weapons duly, and became a great favourite of the gods, the Gandharvas, and the Rakshasas.